# Submit Final Form from modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, submit, final-form

I have issue with my final form. I have a Modal with a react-final-form in it and would like to submit the form with the button which is in the footer of the modal. Submit button has onSubmit event, when I clicked this button I saw that my onSubmit function doesn't work. It works when I click button which opens modal.... What is going wrong here?

Advert.js

```
class Advert extends React.Component {
showLoginMenu = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
this.props.loadModal(LOGIN_MODAL);
};
....
 <button onClick={this.showLoginMenu.bind(this)}>Order</button>
}
```

Modal.js

```
<Modal onClose={this.onClose.bind(this)}>
               <Form
                    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                    initialValues={initValues}
                    decorators={[calculator]}
                    render={({handleSubmit}) => (
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                           <some fields>
                               <button type="submit" onSubmit= 
                               {this.onSubmit}>Order</button>
                        </form>
                    )}
               />
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, onSubmit is a prop of form tag, not button tag. You should use onClick instead.

Comment: I have a similar page with reviews, but with reviews onSubmit works fine. I successfully add review. Сode similar to this, but that modal make that it goes wrong... I dont understand why

Comment: I have the exact same issue, if I put the form component in a regular parent component it works fine, but if I put the form inside a modal it does not work, I do not know why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has probably been resolved by now as this issue is about 2 years old.

But to resolve this issue you need to include the Modal inside of the Form component, but before the form tag

```
<Form
    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
    initialValues={initValues}
    decorators={[calculator]}
    render={({handleSubmit}) => (
        <Modal onClose={this.onClose.bind(this)}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <button type="submit" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>Order</button>
            </form>
         <Modal>
    )}
/>
```